# Symfony3 Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf

Tags: php, ajax, symfony

I try to open a pdf in the iframe but I have this message.
I tried lot of things but no one works.

Thank you.

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf: "data:application/pdf;base64,SFRUUC8xLjAgMjAwIE9LDQpDYWNoZS1Db250cm9sOiBwdWJsaWMNCkNvbnRlbnQtVHlwZTogIGFwcGxpY2F0aW9uL3BkZg0KRGF0ZTogICAgICAgICAgRnJpLCAyMyBGZWIgMjAxOCAxMDowNDowNiBHTVQNCkxhc3QtTW9kaWZpZWQ6IEZyaSwgMjMgRmViIDIwMTggMDk6NDI6NDYgR01UDQoNCg==".

### HTML

```
<iframe class="opendoc" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

### Controller

```
$response = new BinaryFileResponse("path to pdf");
$response->trustXSendfileTypeHeader();
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
$str = base64_encode($response);
return new JsonResponse($str);
```

### Ajax

```
$.ajax({
        url: urlD,            
        type:'POST',              
        data: $(form).serialize(),            
        success:  function (response) {
                $('.opendoc').css('display','block');
                $('.opendoc').attr('src', 'data:application/pdf;base64,'+ response);

                }
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

I will reccomend you to use knp-snappy bundle, there are a lot of useful options and one of them is:

```
Display the pdf in the browser
$snappy = new Pdf('/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf');
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.pdf"');
echo $snappy->getOutput('http://www.github.com');
```

Comment: Thank you, I can't install a new bundle, it's disalowed

Answer (score 0):

You create a BinaryResponse but you send a JsonResponse. Since JsonResponse will set the content type to document/json you get an error.

You probably want to do something similar to this:

```
$str = base64_encode(file_get_contents("path to pdf"));
$response = new Response($str);
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
$response->trustXSendfileTypeHeader();

return $response;
```

Comment: It's doesnt work with $response->trustXSendfileTypeHeader(); 
When I remove this line I have
    Request-URI Too Large
    The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity limit for this server. I saw that was a limitation from apache.